# GetHostByAddress valid anymore?

Tags: .net, dns, powershell-2.0, hostname

All of my PS remoting tools are dependent on a function I wrote that runs the  the following code to resolve the host name.

This stopped working today and now results in this error. 
I looked around and tried GetHostEntry, but this seems to only return the IP address.

```
$Computername = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($IPAddress)).HostName
```

"Exception calling "GetHostByAddress" with "1" argument(s): "The requested 
    name 
    is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"
    At line:1 char:28
    + [Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress <<<< ($IP).HostName
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I would do is to independently confirm that the `PTR` records of interest are still in DNS.  On Windows, I would use `nslookup`.  For example, to find the host information for IP `10.1.2.3`:

```
nslookup
> set type=ptr
> 3.2.1.10.in-addr.arpa.
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find 1.2.3.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
>
```

If you get back an NXDOMAIN, like the above, then doesn't matter what call you're using...the data just isn't there.

If you do get back an answer, then maybe it is in fact the API call.  This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostbyaddress?view=netframework-4.8 does specify that the `GetHostByAddress` method is obsolete and to use `GetHostEntry`, like you tried.  The fact that `GetHostEntry` returned just the IP Address suggests that the `PTR` record is gone, or maybe inaccessible from where you are querying, or maybe you don't have `DNSPermission` as required by that call.